# Java difference between extending and instance variable

Tags: java

I still don't know the difference between creating an instance of a class or extending it. I tried to Google it but I don't know exactly what to look for. Like what does extending a class do what you cannot do with an instance.

Comment: You are typically extending a class because the default functionality is not enough for you and you need to add to it (i.e. extend it).  You create an instance of a class when you intend to use it 'as-is'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an instance of a class means allocating memory on the heap to store the data represented by the class. Extending a class means defining a new class which is based on the original: it has all of the characteristics of the original, plus something new, which you add.

> what does extending a class do what you cannot do with an instance.

They're really quite different sorts of ideas. One defines new capabilities that you can then go on to use (extending), the other takes capabilities that have been defined and puts them into some concrete use.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a class does not create a new instance of it. You merely have a new class which inherits the methods of the parent class and can override some (usually all) of the methods.

An instance of an object is something that you've created via the `new` keyword and it will actively hold data at runtime, however think of extending your class as just creating a new type of class that's similar to another.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the basics of OOP (Object Oriented Programming).  Extending a class and creating an instance of that class are not mutually exclusive.  Extending a class gives you access to any `public` or `protected` properties and methods defined in the parent class.  Anything `private` will not be visible.  I think what you may want to look into is ***extends*** vs ***implements***.  Best of luck getting up to speed.

Comment: I don't get it because creating an object also gives access to any public or protected properties or methods.

Comment: No, when you create an instance of an object you only have access to anything that is declared `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Creating an instance of class`  basically you should understand as create an object (instance) based on type (class). Here class stands for some description (fields) and properties (different methods).

Under `extend class` you should understand that you are specifying the basic type (class that you are extending).

Of course the instantiating of the class leads to the memory consumption.

Basically I recommend you to start your journey at [Oracle Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)